# Should I be doing any casting while sending data from C to arduino over serial?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, arduino, linksys

**My setup:**

Android device =(WiFi)=> Linksys router (WRT54G) =(serial)=> Arduino

Android device : using sockets IO - connects to router
Linksys router : Linux sockets IO - accepts a client
Arduino : reads data serially from router. I have soldered a serial port on the router.

Serial buad rate is 9600 so things are in sync.

**The issue:**
I can see the server printing data properly to the console but I see strange characters in the Arduino console. Here is what I see:

From Android device: `up`

Router console:

```
<Received : up
```

Arduino console:

```
received: BELBELBELBELBELBELBELBELBELBELBELBELBELBELBEL up 
received:
```

I have no idea where this BEL character is coming from?

**My experimentation:**
If I do this from router console window:

```
$> echo "hello" > /dev/tts/1
```

I get proper data on Arduino side i.e. I get this:

```
received: hello
received:
```

**My code:**
Router code

```
int fd;
char *portname = "/dev/tts/1";

fd = open(portname, O_WRONLY);

if (fd < 0)
{
    printf("Error : cannot open port %s\n", portname);
    return -1;
}
...
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &len);
    printf("accept OK!\n");
    printf("accepted connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr));

    char rcvbuf[MAX_BUFF_SIZE] = { '\0' };

    while(1)
    {
        int inData = recv(connfd, rcvbuf, sizeof(rcvbuf), 0);


        if (inData <= 0)
        {
         printf("Client closed!\n");
         break;
        }

        int result = write(fd, rcvbuf, strlen(rcvbuf));

        printf("<Received : %s\n", rcvbuf);

        // reset memory otherwise we will have data
        // from previous data
        bzero((char *)rcvbuff, sizeof(rcvbuf));
     }

...
```

Arduino Code:

```
// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

        while (Serial.available() > 0)
        {
          char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

          if (inChar == '\n' || inChar == '\r' || inChar == '\n\r' || inChar == '\r\n')
          {
            DATA_READ = true;
            break;
          }

          inputString += inChar;          
        }        
        // send data only when you receive data:
        if (DATA_READ) 
        {
          if (inputString[0] != ' ' || inputString[0] != '\n')
          {
            Serial.print("received: ");
            Serial.println(inputString + " " + inputString[0]);

            process_message(inputString[0]);

            // prepare for next round
            DATA_READ = false;

            Serial.flush();
            inputString = "";
          }
        }        
}
```

Any *pointers will be appreciated :)

**EDIT**
added baud rate for more info:
Router

root@OpenWrt:/usr/bin# stty -F /dev/tts/1 -a
**speed 9600 baud;** rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;

Arduino:

```
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(50);
```

Comment: Certain both sides are using the same Baud?  `BEL` or `'\7'` smells like mis-matched Baud.

Comment: `inputString += inChar;` does not look like C to me. Maybe you are using C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a linefeed in the data you write from the router to the arduino, when you send it with the android app? I am not sure if any of these are the cause of your bug, but I recommend:

1. Add the '\n' in android (or in the server).
2. Make sure the android app (java?) is sending ascii characters, if tyou expect ascii characters in the arduino.
3. Use `int inData` as length when you write in the server. Check that its length makes sense.
4. Check `int result` for errors and compare against `inData`